# Update DB using SQL string and WHERE

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to update my DB using PHP string

```
        $sql = "UPDATE client_account 
                status = '".$status."'
            WHERE client = '".$client."'"

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo " Notes ";
} else {

      echo "Notes";
    die;
}
```

I keep on getting error saying syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in

All I want to do is update a row using the WHERE query and just update the one coulomb

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE client_account SET status = '$status' WHERE client = '$client'";

if ($conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "Notes";
} else {
    echo "Notes";
    die;
}

Comment: Double Quotes in python does not require single quote for variables.. but single quotes does require for variables. take that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have `SET` in your update query.

```
$sql = "UPDATE client_account 
           SET status = '".$status."'
        WHERE client = '".$client."'";
```

Edit: Semi-colons are important, too... whoops.

**NOTE**: Thanks to @GrumpyCrouton for pointing this out, this method is susceptible to SQL injection attacks. See his comment below and here: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: And add a `;` in the end.

Comment: @u_mulder Good call.  The semi-colon was the true culprit.

Comment: Thanks yes found the ; at end and forgot the SET thanks

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says the code in your answer is **[may be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)**. **Please** _add a warning about this_, and you should include information on [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Geez, it's been so long since I've stopped doing OP's method and PHP in general that I forgot why this method was bad.  Thankfully I've moved on to Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC.  Good point!